# Ui-router as an API in node.js

Tags: node.js, api, express

Just for understanding, could some tell me is that possible to use ui-router as API call in node.js.

say for example. am having menu navigation like home, about,contact for that we could use like

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.title = 'lolla lo ';
                    $rootScope.metaDescription = 'popcicals popcicals';
                }
            })
            .state('about', {
                url: '/about',
                templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
                controller: function ($rootScope) {
                    $rootScope.title = 'About Us - bla bla bla';
                    $rootScope.metaDescription = 'la la la';
                }
```

is that possible to call that same routing as API call like /myAPI/home
/myAPI/about

since am new to node.js i just want learn from very basic about how to construct simple API with node.js, Express and angular.js 1.x only.

so many resources are given by google god. but not able understand for my level. please do not mark it as duplicate.

share your knowledge, experience.

thank you

Comment: You can use the same url for creating the api in your backend NodeJS but for getting response from api or firing that api, you will need to create a request from your frontend side that is angular.

Comment: @Kamesh thanks for jumping into this. could pls share any example on this. i've tried but cant find related examples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to understand, that back-end routing will handle route since you refresh the page.
In frontend you'll have to make some workaround for incoming values, some `global.data`.
And backend will send this data with the help of some templating on each route - varous data.
Frontend will pull this data on each route - he will know how to handle it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you pls share some live example if possible.  from the front end should pass any parameter to get related api?

Answer (score 0):

In your Frontend side, suppose you have a state myAPI/home and you have the same api in your backend, so you can call that api in your controller like this: or you can also create a service for calling this API for MVC approach.

```
$stateProvider
            .state('myAPI/home', {
                url: '/myAPI/home',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: function ($rootScope, $http) {
                    $rootScope.title = 'lolla lo ';
                    $rootScope.metaDescription = 'popcicals popcicals';
                    $http.get('/myAPI/home').then(function(response){
                        console.log(response)
                    })
                }
            })
```

In your backend side, NodeJS make an api that is triggered when request is made to /myAPI/home url:

```
app.get('/myAPI/home', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello from the other side');
})
```